# Anime that is based from a western movie

Tags: anime-production

There are a lot of western movies that are based from anime, such as [Dragonball Evolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonball_Evolution), [Tekken](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tekken_%282010_film%29), [Blood the Last Vampire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood%3a_The_Last_Vampire_%282009_film%29) (based on [Blood+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood+)), and [Street Fighter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_Fighter_%28film%29). [The Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Matrix) movie is also strongly influenced by [Ghost in the Shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_in_the_Shell_%28film%29) and the action scenes were drew upon their admiration for [Ninja Scroll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ninja_Scroll) and [Akira](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akira_%28film%29).

So my question is, was there an anime produced based on a western movie or series (not on western literature or novel, so movies that are based on novel are excluded) ?

Comment: Not movies, but both Powerpuff Girls and Transformers have anime spin offs.

Comment: The two *Little Witch Academia* productions from Trigger are quite blatantly inspired by Harry Potter; despite Harry Potter being a novel series, I think it deserves a mention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Off the top of my head, there's [Highlander: The Search for Vengeance](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=5552). It was produced by Madhouse and written by David Abramowitz, who worked on the Highlander TV series. Obviously, it's based on the Highlander movie and TV series in the west.

Comment: Another interesting example (though not quite what OP was looking for) is Heroman, written by Stan Lee and animated by Bones.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you comics are counted as Literature or not, but there are anime adaptations of several marvel comics like [X Men](http://myanimelist.net/anime/6919/X-Men), [Iron Man](http://myanimelist.net/anime/6919/X-Men),  [Wolverine](http://myanimelist.net/anime/6918/Wolverine)

Similarly TMNT also was adapted into anime/OVA named [Mutant Ninja Turtles: Superman Legend](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1059/Mutant_Ninja_Turtles:_Superman_Legend)

Also the Video Game [Dragon Age](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Age) was adapted into an anime movie called [Dragon Age: Dawn of the Seeker](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1709652/)